# c# ASP.NET Session Variables Not Initialising Or Updating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

In my project, I'm trying to set the "userid" session variable, however for some reason the session won't initialise. This behaviour is for all session variables in any controller, except my base controller, which uses a different method to set session variables.

Currently, I've tried these ways to set the session variable:

```
Session.Add(...)
Session["keyname"] = "value";
```

I tried to initialise the session in `Global.asax.cs`, with some success, but these variables couldn't be updated :(

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    Session["userid"] = null;
    Session["name"] = null;
}
```

The normal session functionality in ASP.NET was working fine months ago, in this project, the code which uses the session variables hasn't been touched in weeks, and last worked flawlessly.

The `web.config` file has the current session configuration:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" />
<pages enableSessionState="true"/>
```

I've tried everything I've read on this forum and others, but to no avail. I cannot regain "normal" session functionality. Please could someone provide some suggestions? I'm completely lost.

Comment: Check (using F12 developer tools) to ensure your session cookie is being presented to the browser and the browser is sending it back with each request.

Comment: Are you able to replicate same on most browsers?

Comment: No session cookies are being made at any point. Previously I tried setting use cookies attribute to true in the web.config, but this made no difference

Answer (score 0):

Changing this:

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
```

To this:

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" />
```

Fix- enabling cookies over HTTP insecure connections